# C# code displays picture boxes vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: c#, winforms

My code in C# displays picture boxes vertically where the second picture box is below the first one instead of displaying the second picture box horizontally next to the first such that when the width of the visible form overflows. the code creates a new row and continues to create picture boxes. The code reads image file paths from a folder and initializes an array of picture boxes based on the count of the images.  The goal is to create a grid of picture boxes for displaying the images. How can I update the logic of the app to make it achieve the desired output.

```
public class ImageGrid:Form { 
//declare the folder name that contains the complex images 
private string _folder = "./Complex"; //declare the array of picture boxes to display in the form 
private PictureBox[] _image_grid;
private List<string> _paths= new List<string>(); 
public ImageGrid() { 
    //set a title for the form
    Text = "Confidence Level Checker"; 
    //make the screen full                      
    FormBorderStyle = 
    FormBorderStyle.None;
    WindowState =          
    FormWindowState.Maximized;
    //read all the image names in the folder 
    if (Directory.Exists(_folder)) { 
      //list all the files in the folder 
      string[] files = 
      Directory.GetFiles(_folder); 
      if (files != null && files.Length > 0) { 
        //add the paths to the list    
        foreach (var path in files) { 
           _paths.Add(path);
        } 
        //create an array of picture boxes based on the file count 
        _image_grid = new PictureBox[files.Length]; 
        //declare the size of each picture box
        int width = 300; int height = 250; 
        int x = 20; int y = 20;
        foreach (string path in _paths) { 
           PictureBox box = new PictureBox() 
           { 
              Size = new Size(width, height), 
              Location = new Point(x,y),
              Image = Image.FromFile(path), 
              SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage 
           }; 
           //add the picture box to the form 
           this.Controls.Add(box); 
           //update the location to draw the picture box
           x += 320; 
           if (x + 300 > ClientSize.Width) { x = 20; y += 270; } 
       } 
     } 
   }
}
```

Comment: Just use a FlowLayoutPanel and you don't have to worry about setting the Location at all.

Comment: How do I use that type in my code to make it display the picture box horizontally

Comment: I use that as Layout Manager for the form?

Comment: You have choosen the wrong moment to initialize your pictures location. In the form constructor no form still exists. Reading the ClientWidth at this point is likely to return 0. I suggest to move all that code in the Form_Shown event. At that point in time your form is fully initialized and you can count on a correct value for its size

Comment: You change an int x but it is not related to the pboxes.  move the assignment into the loop!

Comment: @Steve, thanks for that, makes a lot of sense. I will generate the event handler and put my code inside

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FlowLayoutPanel() instead to make this simpler.

Then ensure (in the form designer) that the property FlowDirection is set to LeftToRight.

You can also do this in code:

```
myFlowLayoutPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
```

You add controls to a FlowLayoutPanel the same way you do to a standard Panel:

```
myFlowLayoutPanel.Add(someControl);
```